# CSS not displayed depending on page

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, amazon-s3

I have a friend that has a really strange issue with my website. When he clicks on http://www.copeo.fr/ the page displays fine but when he clicks on a link like www.copeo.fr/user/ the CSS is not applied even after a refresh. The raw html does display.

I asked him to display the CSS that is hosted on amazon S3 hcopeoressources.s3.amazonaws.com/style/futurvert/style.css and it displays fine.

The code validates on W3C validator so does the CSS. I am lost what could be the origin of the issue. Could it be its enterprise cache? configuration of IE7 on his machine?

If it happens to someone else who could explain the issue to me, I am all hears.

Thanks

Comment: Strange. Seems to work for me (IE7 in IETester). However, when I test it with IE6 in IETester, every page turns up blank (full white) on the first request and works fine on the second one. That could well be down to IETester, though, it is sometimes unstable. Maybe somebody else can confirm (or deny) this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok got my answer. The firewall blocked the CSS that is stored on amazonaws and for the first page, it was a cache that was filled outside of the company firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like he is using relative path names. `/foo/bar.css` will resolve to `sitename.com/foo/bar.css` but `foo/bar.css` will resolve to `sitename.com/currentpath/foo/bar.css`.

Comment: View source - he doesn't appear to be.

Comment: And it wouldn't explain a bug that only appears for some readers... I totally misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is an IE bug that if you have more than 30 style sheets, some or all of them won't show:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262161

It could possibly have something to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

When I hit the CSS URL I got:

"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below"

We use S3 at work for this type of thing and don't have issues, but I think pulling the CSS file off amazon S3 and storing it on a more traditional server might help with your trouble shooting. Or even solve the issue.